# How to setup constants like this - Constants.Page.Title.MyCase - in C#?

Tags: c#, constants, enumeration

I am trying how figure how to setup like for instance

Color.RGG.Black which equal to "#000000"

I am trying to make it similar like that and implement into my Constants Class. How do I do this?

`Constants.Page.Title.MyCase`    equal to    `"My Case"`;

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set that up by using nested static classes:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static class Page
    {
        public static class Title
        {
            public const string MyCase = "MyCase";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use Namespaces instead of nesting classes, it's probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Although the original poster said they wanted it within their 'Constants' class, though that may have been just because they didn't realise namespaces could be used.

Comment: @Kane: yes this could also be achieved with namespaces. That may be the more elegant way, unless you also want constants defined on "intermediate" levels (such as `Constants.SomeValue` or `Constants.Page.SomeOtherValue`).